# Showing Existence of a Solution for Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing MIT OCW's Honors Differential Equations course (18.034) from 2009 as an independent study for school. I came across the following problem on Problem Set 2 and it confused me:

2. Suppose that $f$ be a continuous bounded function for the entire real axis. If $f'$ is continuous,
   then show that the nonzero solution of the initial value problem of $y' = yf\left(y\right)$ with $y\left(0\right) = y_0 \ne 0$
   exists for all x. (You may need to assume the uniqueness theorem.

My first instinct was to rearrange then integrate, getting to $\int_{y_0}^y \frac{dt}{tf\left(t\right)} = x$. However, I do not know if the left side is integrable because the function $f$ may equal $0$ over the interval. Even if this is not the case, then suppose $\frac{1}{yf\left(y\right)}$ has antiderivative $H\left(y\right)$. Then, $H\left(y\right) = x + H\left(y_0\right) \implies y = H^{-1}(x + H\left(y_0\right))$. However, I wasn't sure if could assume that $H^{-1}$ is defined for all inputs, so with this uncertainty I wouldn't be able to determine from this that the solution exists for all x.

Eventually I looked at the solution given on OCW's website and was able to follow it for the most part. I know $f$ being bounded implies $|f| ≤ M$ for some nonnegative $M$. So $\frac{y'}{y} ≤ |f\left(y\right)| ≤ M$, or $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln |y|) ≤ M$. This implies that $\ln |y| - \ln |y_0| ≤ Mx$, so $|y\left(x\right)| ≤ |y_0|e^{Mx}$. Then, we consider the rectangle where $|x| ≤ a$ and $|y| ≤ |y_0|e^{Mx}$ for some positive $a$.

I am able to follow the given solution up until that point, but here is the part the confused me. Suppose the solution does not exist over the interval $|x| < a$. Then, $|y\left(a\right)| = |y_0|e^{Ma}$. After this, the solution finishes with "[t]his contradicts (??)." I thought the (??) may be a formatting error so I assume it means (1), which refers to $|y\left(x\right)| ≤ |y_0|e^{Mx}$; however, I don't see how the equality would contradict this inequality.

What exactly would the contradiction be here? Or, is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: There is a consequence of the Picard theorem (which establishes short time existence of solutions) which says that the only way a solution to your problem fails to exist is if it blows up in finite time. The proof comes from the fact that for any compact $K$ there is a uniform time of existence for solutions starting at $x_0 \in K$. You'll need to look at the details of the estimates used to invoke Picards theorem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use argument by contradiction to show. By the Picard theorem, there is $x_0>0$ such that the equation has a unique solution $y(x)$ in $[0,x_0]$. Extends this solution to the maximal interval $[0, x_0)$ (still use $x_0$). Now either $x_0=\infty$ or $x_0$ is finite. If $x_0=\infty$, it is done. Otherwise $x_0<\infty$ and then we must have
$$ \lim_{x\to x_0^-} |y(x)|=\infty. \tag 1$$
On the other hand, from the equation, we have
$$ \frac{y'}{y}=f(y) $$
which gives after integrating from $0$ from $x\in(0,x_0)$
$$ \ln|y(x)|-\ln|y_0|=\int_0^{x} f(y(t))dt\le \int_0^{x} |f(y(t))|dt\le Mx $$
where $f(x)$ is supposed to be bounded so that there is $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$. So
$$ |y(x)|\le|y_0| e^{Mx}. $$
Thus
$$\lim_{x\to x_0^-} |y(x)|\le |y_0| e^{Mx_0} $$
which is against (1).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! I see how the contradiction would follow if (1) is true, but how exactly would I go about proving (1) if x0 is not infinite? I looked into Picard's theorem and Picard iteration to see if I can prove it from there but I was unable to figure out how to do it.

Comment: If (1) fails, this will be again the assumption that $[0,x_0]$ is the largest extension.